# Delphi ADOQuery not picking up record after another ADOQuery inserted it

Tags: sql, delphi, ado

I am not sure why this is occurring so I will explain the situation briefly (should be easy to follow):

Form1 a procedure that executes a  sql select statement and displays it on a dbgrid linked to a ADOQuery1 component via a TDataSource component:

```
procedure form1. Selectp;
begin
   ADOQuery1.Active:=false;
   ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:='select * from tbl';
   ADOQuery1.Active:=true;
end;
```

Form1 has a button that opens a new form to enter record fields:

```
procedure form1. buttonaddrecordClick(Sender: TObject);
var
form2:Tform;
begin
   form2:=Tform2.Create(nil); 
   try
      form2.ShowModal; 
   finally
      form2.Release; 
   end;
   selectp;//executes but new record doesn’t show up although in database;
end;
```

Form2 has a procedure that inserts values into database through form2.ADOQuery2.

```
procedure form2.Insertp;
begin
    ADOQuery2.Active:=false;
    ADOQuery2.SQL.Text:='insert into tbl (field1) values ('''+ sfield +''')';
    ADOQuery2.ExecSql;
    ModalResult := mrOk;
end;
```

If I place a button on form1 to run selectp I have to press it 2+ times before the new record shows up but it doesn’t matter how many times I call selectp after showmodal in buttonaddrecord the new record doesnt show up.

What is causing this and how can it be corrected?

Comment: Since you're using a different SQL query component, call just [`TADOQuery1.Refresh`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Refresh) to re-fetch your data.

Comment: Tried it before - gives an error: insufficient key column for updating or refreshing.But if you look in DB the new record is there.

Comment: What Does this Error mean?

Comment: It seems you can't call `Refresh` for queries of tables whose are not having primary key. I never met this before, since all key tables I've been working with were having a primary key.

Comment: With out primary key you could try [ADODataSet.Requery](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.Requery), but you should have an primary key anyway.

Comment: Thanks this works but as a side note my table does have a Primary Key-checked it in access just now.

Comment: @Rayman, are all primary key columns in the result set for the query?

Comment: @MarcusAdams by result set do you mean in my select statement-if so I think you are right since only one of the PK columns is in the select statement(other than in join part).PK of each of the 3 tables queried here is an ID number so I only need to display one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `TDataSource` linked to `ADOQuery1` has no way of knowing that ***another*** `ADOQuery2` made changes to the DB.

Either you call [`ADOQuery1.Requery`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.Requery) ***after*** you insert a new row via `ADOQuery2` (It is very much like `DataSet.Close` followed by `DataSet.Open`) , Or you can pass `ADOQuery1` reference to `Tform2`, and insert a new record like so:

```
ADOQuery1.Append;
// If you do not have some auto-inc primary key (or other) - generate it manually:
ADOQuery1.FieldByName('id').AsString := some_new_unique_id;
ADOQuery1.FieldByName('field1').AsString := sfield;
ADOQuery1.Post;
```

The changes should reflect in the `TDBGrid` that linked to the `TDataSource`.

---

Notes:

- No need to call `ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear` since you are assigning the SQL via `ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := '...'`
- `INSERT INTO` SQL statement should be followed by `ADOQuery2.ExecSQL` (not `ADOQuery2.Active := true`) since you do not return a cursor to data.